# "Contains" search for a sub-element of an object array

Tags: angularjs

Here's my data:

```
[
    {profile: {name: "Test123"}}
]
```

I have a text input, like so:

```
<input ng-model="searchText">
```

I'm trying to do a search on `profile.name` using the textbox input.

I've tried making a custom filter, like so:

```
$scope.searchFilter = function(value){
    return value.profile.name.indexOf($scope.searchText) != -1;
};
```

Then filtering like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="profile in profiles | filter: searchFilter"></tr>
```

It seems unfortunately that this works fine on the initial search, but when entering text into the textbox the filter is not re-evaluated.

How can I force Angular to re-check the filter when I enter text into the search box, **or is there a better way to do this**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a function to search. Just change your html into this:

```
<input ng-model="searchText.profile.name" /> 
...
<tr ng-repeat="data in profiles | filter: searchText">{{data.profile.name}}</tr>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.searchText = { profile: {name:""}}; //should be the same data struct with your search target.
$scope.profiles = [
    {profile: {name: "Someone"}},
    {profile: {name: "Luky"}},
    {profile: {name: "John"}},
    {profile: {name: "Mary"}},
    {profile: {name: "Howard"}},
    {profile: {name: "Sheldon"}}
]
```

Then it works. [Here is jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/k9za1y1a/2/) : )

[And here is filter document.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)